# How to Write Multiple Rows/Arrays to CSV File in one attempt using PHP?

Tags: php, file, csv, file-handling, fputcsv

I have to write multiple records in csv file. I'm using fputcsv function of php which take array as one row and write it in the file. In this way there will be multiple write operations for each row.

I'm looking for a method with which I can write multiple rows in one write operation to csv file.

Please help.

Comment: So just use `fwrite`?

Comment: Share with us your code to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! It Worked

Comment: This question could do with more detail and context to get sensible answers. Why is writing one line at a time not an option? How many is multiple;  2 lines, 200 million lines?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

***Solution 1:*** Saving Data in String and then using **fwrite** worked!

Code:

```
$file = 'test.csv';

$file = fopen($file, 'w');

$content = '';

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $content.="a,b,c,d\r\n";
}

fwrite($file, $content);

fclose($file);
```

***Solution 2:*** as suggested by @chiliNUT using output buffer.

Code:

```
$handle = fopen("php://output", "w");
$data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
ob_start();
foreach ($data as $dat) {
    fputcsv($handle, $dat);
}
$csvContent = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents("csv.csv", $csvContent);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using the memory stream. It should give you a structure that you can customize to work through the buffer in pieces and reset progress if the buffer gets too big.

```
<?php
// Sample data
$arrData = array(
  array("Fruit","Color","Calories"),
  array("Apple","Red",95),
  array("Orange","Orange",45),
  array("Plum","Purple",45)  
);

// Open output file
$fpOut = fopen("bufferedWrite.csv", "w");

// Write to memory stream
$msBuffer = fopen("php://memory","w+");
foreach($arrData as $arrRecord)
{
  fputcsv($msBuffer, $arrRecord);
}

// Rewind back to the beginning of the buffer and save the contents into a file in one big write
rewind($msBuffer);
fwrite($fpOut, stream_get_contents($msBuffer));

// Close the memory stream
fclose($msBuffer);

// Close the output file
fclose($fpOut);
```

Comment: stream_copy_to_stream() might be even better

Answer (score 1):

If your worried about doing multiple write operations, you can "write" the csv to the output buffer, capture the output buffer with `ob_start()`/`ob_get_clean()`, then dump the buffer into a csv, like this:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("php://output", "w");
$data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
ob_start();
foreach ($data as $dat) {
    fputcsv($handle, $dat);
}
$csvContent = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents("csv.csv", $csvContent);
```