# How to write data in multiple rows of csv file without loop using PHP?

Tags: php, file, csv

I am trying to write multiple rows to CSV file without using a loop. 
Actually, I have a single column SKU in my CSV file. I have an array of multiple SKUs.m I want to write those SKUs into CSV without using any loop.
Can anyone know then please guide me?

I have looked this below thread but it is not what I require

[How to Write Multiple Rows/Arrays to CSV File in one attempt using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451299/how-to-write-multiple-rows-arrays-to-csv-file-in-one-attempt-using-php?rq=1)

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using the function `implode()`? You might do something like `$contentRows = implode("\n", $rows)`. (technically that is still a loop, but it will probably perform better than using foreach())

Comment: I have to ask why? Whats wrong with a loop??

Comment: @TobiasF.I am going to try this. Can you please let me know how I will use it with fputcsv() function? Can I do this like fputcsv($file,$contentRows); ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know the loop way but I though there must be better way to write a csv file in single line of code.

Comment: @TobiasF. implode didn't work here. because fputcsv require array not a string.

Comment: I have tried to write array using fputcsv function and it put the each index value to different columns . seems it wokred for column wise not row wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function in PHP?

```
array_map(function($element){ fputcsv($file, [$element]) }, $sku_array);
```

This is a form of functional programming, that eschews traditional looping structures.